# Где в Visual Studio можно поменять правило автогенерации имен для полей?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Например, я создал конструктор, где получаю параметры, но ничего не присваиваю.

Visual Studio предлагает мне создать поля под каждое присваиваемое значение и выполнить инициализацию.

Однако, создаются они без нижнего подчеркивания... Можно где-то это поменять? В разделе стилей настроек я не нашел этого момента...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603580/5045688 - способ рабочий, сам его использую.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а ответом сюда не продублируете, что бы был русифицированная версия вопроса.